# Debugging nestjs application with --watch from vscode with docker stops on changed file

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, nestjs, watch

I am trying to debug a typescript nestjs application in `--watch` mode (so it restarts when files are changed) in Visual Studio code (using the Docker extension). The code is mounted in docker through the use of a volume.

It almost works perfectly, the docker is correctly launched, the debugger can attach, however I have one problem that I can't seem to work out:

As soon as a file is changed, the watcher picks it up and I see the following in `docker logs -f` for the container:

```
[...]
[10:12:59 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[10:12:59 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/af60f5e3-394d-4df3-a565-8d15898348bf
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
user@system:~$
# (at this point the docker logs command stops and the docker is gone)
```

At that point vscode ends the debugging session, the docker stops (or vice versa?) and I have to manually restart it.

If I launch the exact same docker command (copy/pasted from the vscode terminal window) manually, it does not stop when changing a file. This is the command it generates:

```
docker run -dt --name "core-dev" -e "DEBUG=*" -e "NODE_ENV=development" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" -v "/home/user/projects/core:/usr/src/app" -p "4000:4000" -p "9229:9229" --workdir=/usr/src/app "node:14-buster" yarn run start:dev --debug 0.0.0.0:9229
```

I did try to look with strace what happens and this is what I see on the node process when I change any file:

```
strace: Process 28315 attached
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=40, si_uid=0, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=79, si_stime=9} ---
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

The `killed by SIGKILL` line does **not** happen when docker is run manually, it only happens when it's started from vscode when debugging.

Hopefully someone has an idea where I'm going wrong.

Here are the relevant configs:

**launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker Node.js Launch",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "platform": "node"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "dockerRun": {
                "customOptions": "--workdir=/usr/src/app",
                "image": "node:14-buster",
                "command": "yarn run start:dev --debug 0.0.0.0:9229",
                "ports": [{
                    "hostPort": 4000,
                    "containerPort": 4000
                }],
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "localPath": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "containerPath": "/usr/src/app"
                    }
                ],
                "env": {
                    "DEBUG": "*",
                    "NODE_ENV": "development"
                }
            },
            "node": {
                "enableDebugging": true,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a hello world repo: https://github.com/strikernl/nestjs-docker-hello-world

Comment: Have you investigated which process sends the signal (it had PID 40 in the example)? I might be wrong but I think it's VSCode sending it.

Comment: @anemyte it looks like pid 40 is coming from within the docker. It's this one:
```root        40  4.6  0.1 676620 55424 pts/0    Sl+  21:40   0:00 /usr/local/bin/node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 /usr/src/app/dist/main``` (apologies for the formatting). There's no pid 40 on the host, anyhow.

Comment: I expected it to come from inside just by low PID number. I'd like to dig into this if you can supply me with minimal 'hello-world' example to reproduce it locally. I tried myself but with my poor node.js knowledge I failed to make `--watch` work.

Comment: @anemyte thank you! This should generally do the trick: https://github.com/strikernl/nestjs-docker-hello-world -- the first run will take some time because it will run `yarn install` to install all the packages (I edited that into `tasks.json`). VScode will also timeout, but the second run will work.

Answer (score 7):

So here's what I found out. When you change code it restarts node's debugger process. VSCode kills Docker container when it loses connection to the debugger.

There is a nice feature which restarts debugger sessions on code changes (see [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_restarting-debug-sessions-automatically-when-source-is-edited)) but the problem is - it is for `"type": "node"` launch configurations. Yours is `"type": "docker"`. From it's [options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common) for `node` only `autoAttachChildProcesses` seems promising but it doesn't solve the problem (I've checked).

So my suggestion is:

1. Create a `docker-compose.yml` file, which will start the container instead of VSCode.
2. Edit your `launch.json` so that it attaches to the `node` in container and restarts debugger session on changes.
3. Remove/rework `tasks.json` as it is not needed in it's current state.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: "3.0"

services:
    node:
        image: node:14-buster
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        command: yarn run start:dev --debug 0.0.0.0:9229
        ports:
            - 4000:4000
            - 9229:9229
        volumes:
            - ${PWD}:/usr/src/app
        environment:
            DEBUG: "*"
            NODE_ENV: "development"
```

**launch.json**:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "restart": true,
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Save the `docker-compose.yml` in your project root and use `docker-compose up` to start the container (you may need to install it first https://docs.docker.com/compose/ ). Once it's working start the debugger as usual.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing myself to get it working currently, but I was hoping to get it so that it runs a docker instance on demand. I'll set your answer as the accepted one if it turns out it's impossible to do it in vscode that way (or if no other answer comes soonish). Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: There is an option to create several launch configurations in launch.json: one to start the container, another to attach to it. The only difference is that you'd have to click button in VSCode to start the container instead of going for docker-compose. I tried it and it appeared to me as unstable and not straightforward solution. If it feels a better solution to you, I will update the answer with it.
Apart from that I believe there is no fix until the restart feature gets into docker launch type.